# Shapely LineString: How to project using "my" distance?

Tags: python, shapely

I have a `line = LineString([p0, p1, p2, p3])` and I want to project a point`p` into it but with a twist.

If I do `line.project(p)`, the result is measured in the plane along `line` starting at `p0`. But I need to know whether the projection lies between `p0` and `p1`, or between `p1` and `p2`, etc. So I need a float that ranges from `0` to `1` if `p` projects to the segment `[p0, p1]`, or ranges from `1` to `2` if `p` projects to `[p1, p2]`, etc.

My use case is this: assume `p0, p1, p2, p3` are the positions of an object at times `t=0, 1, 2, 3`. Then I need to know at which time the object passed the closest to `p`. This is different to know how much it had traveled from `p0`, which is what `project` gives me.

I'm currently doing a `for` with the segments `LineString([pi, pi+1])` and using `project` against each of them, to select the closest one. This works, but there might be something better.

Comment: Are `[p0, p1, p2, p3]` at equal distance from each other?

Comment: @Eagnir, no, they aren't

Comment: When you create the `line` variable, you should save the `distances` of all the points from p0 and then when you use `line.project(p)` you can match the distance closest to it from your `distances` list. You can fairly quickly calc the distance based on [geometric formula](https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/distance-between-two-points/) √[(x2 − x1)^2 + ( y2 − y1)^2]. This way you are not actually performing calculations every time p moves but just comparisons. I am sure you can speed this whole process up as vectors but that also adds complexity.